# Javascript works in Firefox but now in Chrome when coming from web server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ubuntu, apache2

I'm testing a web page that hides and unhides a div container when a different one is clicked on. I tested this is Chrome and it worked nicely, but after I put it on my web server I get undefined errors. When I test it in Firefox from the web server, it works fine. It works fine with Chromium in Lubuntu, but Chrome in Windows is giving me an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 

"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Chrome test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function hideDiv(nameId) {
                var grouping = document.getElementById(nameId); 
                if(grouping.style.display == 'none') {
                    grouping.style.display = '';
                } else {
                    grouping.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="group">
            <div id="header" onclick="hideDiv('failingtoclose');">
                <span>Testing</span>
            </div>
            <div id="failingtoclose">
                <span>More testing</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The warning the developer's tools gives me: 
'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.

and the error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined (Line 9)

The web server is running apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu.

Comment: what is the value of grouping?

Answer (score 0):

it's working fine in chrome on windows (version  30.0.1599.69 m) and I doubt it has to do with the server since there is no interaction going on, at least in the code you provide. Changing the doctype to standards mode (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) might help, since some browsers get confused otherwise (though I doubt chrome does).

Comment: Just opening the file directly with Chrome works fine for me as well, I only have a problem when opening it from the web server. That is also the version of Chrome I am using.

Comment: No, still the same issue.

Comment: well, what's the value of grouping then, when you run the code and it fails?

Comment: Chrome's developer's tools gives me "" as the value of grouping in those instances.

Comment: what if you use jquery to handle the event and get the failingToClose div? Also, what does `console.debug(JSON.stringify(grouping));` return?

Comment: That yields the same result.